# Find an algorithm to find $\lambda$.

Tags: logic

Let $\alpha$ be a well-formed formula and $\lambda$ any word. Show that if $(\alpha)\lambda$ is a well-formed formula, then $\lambda$ has the form $\ast (\beta)$, where $\ast$ is a binary connective and $\beta$ is a well-formed formula.

Where $(\alpha)\lambda$ is the concatenation of the symbols of $\alpha$ with those of $\lambda$.

The idea that I have to do it is to find an algorithm for this, but I don't know how to do the algorithm, someone help me. Or try to do it in another way but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the language you are working on? If it is specified, one can then perform induction on $\lambda$.

Comment: Are you telling me to apply induction in formulas? And I don't understand, like, in what language? @Jason

Comment: Which exactly is the set of well formed formulae that you mention?